# nodejs' spawn and exec using pdf2swf

Tags: node.js, flash, exec, spawn, pdf2swf

I hope that there is someone that can help with this problem since I don't get it myself.

I compiled the newest version of pdf2swf and everything is working fine, except of when I want to use it as a spawned child_process in NodeJS.

When I use the same command as a exec, it works again.
To provide some code example:

```
// convert a pdf to swf using exec (works)
var tmpSwfLocation = docsDir+'/Paper.pdf.swf';
var pdf2swf = cp.exec('pdf2swf '+tmpPDFLocation+' -o '+tmpSwfLocation+' -G -v -f -T 9 -t -j '+quality+' -s subpixels='+resolution+' -s storeallcharacters -s poly2bitmap', function(err, stdout, stderr){
  console.log(stdout);
  console.log(stderr);
  var end = Date.now();
  console.log('pdf2swf: SWF created in '+((end-start) /1000)+' seconds');
});

// convert a pdf to swf (does not work)
var tmpSwfLocation = docsDir+'/Paper.pdf.swf';
var pdf2swf = cp.spawn('pdf2swf', ['-G','-v','-f','-T 9', '-t', '-j '+quality,'-s subpixels='+resolution,'-s storeallcharacters', '-s poly2bitmap',tmpPDFLocation, '-o '+tmpSwfLocation],{setsid:true});
pdf2swf.stdout.on('data',function(output){
  console.log("pdf2swf:"+output)
});
pdf2swf.stderr.on('data',function(output){
  console.log("pdf2swf ERROR:"+output);
});
pdf2swf.stdout.on('end', function(output){
  var end = Date.now();
  console.log('pdf2swf: SWF created in '+((end-start) /1000)+' seconds');
});
```

The spawn process breaks in the very end, when the child_process is trying to write data into the file:

```
pdf2swf:NOTICE  Writing SWF file  /home/bitnami/flipdoc/ec2-instances/worker/pdf_test/test_directory/test-Testfile_31MB_26Pages.pdf_0/docs/Paper.pdf.swf
pdf2swf:FATAL   Could not create " /home/bitnami/flipdoc/ec2-instances/worker/pdf_test/test_directory/test-Testfile_31MB_26Pages.pdf_0/docs/Paper.pdf.swf".
```

Using exec, the process finalizes successfully with

```
pdf2swf:NOTICE  Writing SWF file  /home/bitnami/flipdoc/ec2-instances/worker/pdf_test/test_directory/test-Testfile_31MB_26Pages.pdf_0/docs/Paper.pdf.swf
```

and a existent file.

Additional information:
Before the whole process I execute a recursive chmod 777 on the whole "test_directory".

Greets

Comment: `setsid` doesn't appear to be a valid option for `spawn`.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to write that I was using node 0.6.18, in which setsid was still a valid option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it myself... Never (in the means of don't even think about it...) use spaces in the arguments to the spawn process. if you have a param=value argument which can use spaces in between, just row them up in the array with every other argument.

the source code from above for spawn looks now like this:

```
var pdf2swf = cp.spawn('pdf2swf', [tmpPDFLocation, '-o',tmpSwfLocation,'-G','-vvv','-f','-T','9', '-t', '-j',quality,'-s','subpixels='+resolution,'-s','storeallcharacters', '-s','poly2bitmap']);
```

Comment: Also, don't provide blank strings! I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why some third party npm module wasn't working... I think the maintainer has never tested his code without changing the options from default because there were ternary operators in the array that provided blank strings if the option wasn't the default.